# R summary of a matrix returning 0's and number of NA's instead of statistics

Tags: r, matrix, na, summary

I have four 3d matrices: `sliced_qbot.Rdata`, `sliced_q2m.Rdata`, `sliced_ubot.Rdata`, and `sliced_vbot.Rdata [256,128,360]`.  The first two  matrices have a mix of reals and `NA`'s and the last two have all reals.  However, when I try to obtain summary statistics for the two `NA` containing matrices using:

```
summary(sliced_q2m.Rdata) 
summary(sliced_qbot.Rdata)
```

It returns `min=0 q1=0 med=0 mean=0 q3=0 max=0, NA's =7212960` for both

Whereas `summary(sliced_ubot.Rdata)` and `summary(sliced_vbot.Rdata)` do not have any NA values and return and actual summary.  I'm not sure why summary isn't working for the two matrices with NA values, but it works for the two without NA values.

Comment: It works for me — are you sure that the `NA` containing matrices contain anything but `NA`s and 0s?

Comment: Yes, the matrices have a total 117,96,480 slots and the two have 45,83,520 non-NA non-0 entries.

Comment: It sounds like the variables are too large to include in the question. Are you able to take a subset of each array (perhaps `summary(sliced_qbot[1:3,1:3,1:3])`, etc) and still get the errant behavior? If so, please make this question reproducible and show us some sample data (with `dput(...)`, for instance). Otherwise, I'm afraid you may not get much of an answer.

Comment: I used a small subset that contained NA's summary worked as it should have:
`> summary(sliced_q2m[14:16,14:16,14:16])
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.               NA's 
0.000411 0.000672 0.000779 0.001120 0.001468 0.002387       12`

However, it seems as I increase the size of the subset it starts reverting back to 0's across the board

Comment: Mike Zizzi, beware of those [known issues with `summary()`'s inconsistent rounding of numeric arguments](https://www.r-bloggers.com/my-criticism-of-r-numeric-summary/) due to bad default behavior. See linked article by John Mount. Perhaps an enhance request can be formulated on the treatment of defaults.

Answer (score 2):

DOH! Okay so I just had to increase the number of digits displayed.  Most of my data points are really small numbers, so I should have realized I would need more digit spaces.

`> options(digits=20)` 
`> summary(sliced_q2m)` returns an actual summary

Min.1st Qu.                 Median                   Mean 
2.6467755999999998e-06 5.5907318890000002e-04 3.2247315394000001e-03 4.8551256022999999e-03 
               3rd Qu.                   Max.                   NA's 
6.6539720865000001e-03 2.3001585155700000e-02                7212960

Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this is due to display rounding.

```
set.seed(42)
rndm <- rexp(10000, 1e8)
summary(rndm)
#      Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
# 1.950e-12 2.876e-09 6.887e-09 1.007e-08 1.413e-08 1.058e-07 
summary(matrix(rndm, ncol = 2))
#        V1                  V2           
#  Min.   :1.950e-12   Min.   :2.720e-12  
#  1st Qu.:2.946e-09   1st Qu.:2.811e-09  
#  Median :6.967e-09   Median :6.823e-09  
#  Mean   :1.023e-08   Mean   :9.896e-09  
#  3rd Qu.:1.417e-08   3rd Qu.:1.408e-08  
#  Max.   :8.462e-08   Max.   :1.058e-07
```

Inject a single `NA` to trigger a slightly different logic for display:

```
summary(matrix(c(NA, rndm[-1]), ncol = 2))
#        V1              V2           
#  Min.   :0e+00   Min.   :2.720e-12  
#  1st Qu.:0e+00   1st Qu.:2.811e-09  
#  Median :0e+00   Median :6.823e-09  
#  Mean   :0e+00   Mean   :9.896e-09  
#  3rd Qu.:0e+00   3rd Qu.:1.408e-08  
#  Max.   :1e-07   Max.   :1.058e-07  
#  NA's   :1
```

You can dive in a little to look at the first column with:

```
summary(matrix(c(NA, rndm[-1]), ncol = 2)[,1])
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
#   0e+00   0e+00   0e+00   0e+00   0e+00   1e-07       1
```

which still looks all zeroes until

```
str(summary(matrix(c(NA, rndm[-1]), ncol = 2)[,1]))
# Classes 'summaryDefault', 'table'  Named num [1:7] 1.95e-12 2.95e-09 6.97e-09 1.02e-08 1.42e-08 ...
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7] "Min." "1st Qu." "Median" "Mean" ...
```

which shows that the actual statistics are just very small numbers and rounded for display purposes.

You can also confirm this is a display-rounding issue with this:

```
options(digits=15)
summary(matrix(c(NA, rndm[-1]), ncol = 2))
#        V1                      V2                   
#  Min.   :1.9490000e-12   Min.   :2.71670054640e-12  
#  1st Qu.:2.9464250e-09   1st Qu.:2.81112083154e-09  
#  Median :6.9705950e-09   Median :6.82337492704e-09  
#  Mean   :1.0235797e-08   Mean   :9.89606947511e-09  
#  3rd Qu.:1.4169548e-08   3rd Qu.:1.40828140108e-08  
#  Max.   :8.4623358e-08   Max.   :1.05845029551e-07  
#  NA's   :1
```

Comment: I literally just figured that out.  Thanks for the help!